# Skype does not save user configuration

Tags: 10.10, configuration, skype

On Ubuntu 10.10, I have recently started to experience this problem:

For some reason Skype won't save any settings except "Sign in on startup". When Skype starts and tries to sign in it is unsuccessful (it shows incorrect password, in red) every time (I have provided the correct password).

I always have to click to show contacts in groups, it does not remember it. Every time I have to go to options and update some notification settings.

I know all these things should be "remembered" by Skype - this problem started only recently. I don't recall fiddling with any permissions that could have likely caused that.

Do you know what the problem might be? I uninstalled (marking for complete configuration removal) and re-installed Skype, but it still remembers my username (why??).

Can I find Skype configuration files on the filesystem somewhere and change permissions for them - or even better - edit the files to set what I want?

Comment: Uninstall including configuration files will only purge the program's configuration files, but not user data in your `/home`-directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename your `~/.Skype` folder to something like `~/.Skype-old`.

Now sign in to Skype fresh, and it will reset itself. You can now copy the contents from the old folder that you want to preserve to your new `~/.Skype` folder :).
You can also check the permissions of the files in that folder to ensure that Skype can read and write them correctly. If they seem correct and you still get problems, try running a disk check, which might fix any errors with the file-system (just in case)

Comment: thanks, a good hint. But I don't want to remove all my chat history, bookmarked chats etc.

Comment: you won't lose bookmarked chats, maybe your chat history, but all you have to do is back it up.

Comment: I found how to do it. When I just deleted .Skype, I lost bookmarked chats + history. For my issue I deleted all xml and lock/lck files :) thanks

Comment: cool ^^ glad you got it working :D